# $\text{Tot}$ is not computably enumerable

Tags: logic, solution-verification, recursion, computability

I'm trying to show that $Tot=\{e: \phi_e \text{ is total}\}$ is not c.e.

<s>Suppose that $Tot$ is c.e. Then its semi-characteristic function is computable. Then the following function $\eta$ is computable:$$\eta(x)\uparrow \text{if } x\in Tot\\ \eta(x)\downarrow \text{ if } x\notin Tot$$</s>

Let $U$ be a universal function. Since $\eta$ is computable, there is $p$ such that $$U(p,x)=\eta(x)$$ for all $x$. $Tot$ can be written as $\{e: U(e,-) \text{ is total}\}$ so setting $x=p$ above we have

$$U(p,p)\uparrow \text{ if } U(p,x)\downarrow\text{ for all } x\\ U(p,p)\downarrow \text{ if } U(p,x_0)\uparrow \text{ for some } x_0$$

There's a contradiction in the first line (but not in the second). Is that enough to conclude that $Tot$ is not c.e.? If not, then how to prove the required result properly?

---

Actually, now that I've written this proof I started to doubt that $\eta$ is computable. In fact, I don't think that it's computable. How to prove the claim then? (One way is to show that $Tot$ is $\Pi_2$-complete, and hence cannot be $\Sigma_1$, but I wanted a direct proof using some kind of diagonilization argument.)

Comment: I'm not sure if they are just typos or conceptual errors, but here's a couple of points: first of all $\eta$ must converge if $x$ in $Tot$ and diverge otherwise. Then it is correct that $\eta$ has its own index $p$, but then $Tot = \{ x : U(p,x) \downarrow \}$, which is not what you wrote. I stopped reading here, as I'm not sure where you want to go from here.

Comment: Btw, I wrote an explicit reduction from $\emptyset''$ to $Tot$ a some time ago, which certainly implies your claim: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616131/explicit-turing-reduction-of-0-to-tot/3617311#3617311

Comment: @Manlio I took $\eta$ to be a modified semi-characteristic function, but as I pointed out at the very end, after writing that "proof" I realized that it's not computable.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help with a question that has mostly been crossed out.

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward proof:

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to Tot$ be a computable surjection. Then consider the function $g(x) = \phi_{f(x)}(x) + 1$. $g$ is also a computable total function. Therefore, there must exist $n$ such that $\phi_n = g$. Then in particular, there must exist some $x$ such that $\phi_{f(x)} = g$. But in that case, we would have $g(x) = \phi_{f(x)}(x) = \phi_{f(x)}(x) + 1$; contradiction.

Since there is no computable surjection $\mathbb{N} \to Tot$, and since $Tot$ has infinitely many elements, we see that $Tot$ is not computably enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using the many-one reduction :

$\bullet$ $\text{Tot}:= \{e \in \mathbb N \mid \phi_e \ \text{is total and computable}\} \in \Pi_2^0$.

Indeed : $e\in \text{Tot} \Leftrightarrow \forall x \phi_e(x) \downarrow \Leftrightarrow \forall x \exists t T^1[e,x,t]$ where $T^1$ is the Kleene predicate which is recursive. Hence $\text{Tot} \in \Pi_2^0$.

$\bullet$ $\text{Tot} \in \Pi_2^0$-complete. Let us show that for all $A\in \Pi_2^0$ : $A \le_m \text{Tot}$.

As $A\in \Pi_2^0$, we can write $A:= \{e \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall x \exists y R(e,x,y)\}$ where $R$ is a recursive predicate.

Consider the following function : $g(e,x)= \mu y.R(e,x,y)$ (given $e\in \mathbb{N}$ and an entry $x$, we try to find the smallest witness such that the predicate $R$ holds and if it is found, the procedure halts). The function $g$ is in particular computable (partially). Hence it has an index $j\in \mathbb{N}$.

Using the *smn* theorem, we can justify the existence of a total computable function $f$ such that $f(e)=s_1^1(j,e)$. Notice that now $f(e)$ is an index for $g$.

Hence $e\in A \Leftrightarrow \forall x g(e,x) \downarrow \Leftrightarrow \forall x \phi_{f(e)}(x) \downarrow \Leftrightarrow \phi_{f(e)} \ \text{is total} \Leftrightarrow f(e) \in \text{Tot}$.

Hence $A \le_m \text{Tot}$ and $\text{Tot}$ is $\Pi_2^0$-complete.

We conclude that $\text{Tot}$ cannot be computably enumerable.